# How to select from multiple lists with Linq?

Tags: c#, class, linq-to-entities

I have this sql select :

```
select a.*
from a inner join b on (a.col1=b.col1 and a.col2=b.col2)
```

Let's assume that a, b are now lists.Can you help me to write this select , in c# , Linq , with lambda expressions?

Comment: This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Lists of what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is
    `Enumerable.Join<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>`,
see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
from a inner join b on (a.col1=b.col1 and a.col2=b.col2)
```

Could be transformed into LINQ like this:

```
a.Join(b, aItem => aItem.col2, bItem => bItem.col2,
(aItem, bItem) => new { aItem = aItem, bItem = bItem, col2 = aItem.col2);
```